# Simple multifile c++11 compilation g++ when defining personal namespace in classes

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

Working with a Fedora g++, I've noticed something anoying for me. 
I think I misundertands g++ behaviors with namesapce and header files.

You will see 2 versions of a very simple Class and a main function.

- First one is fully embeded in  single file named "mainfull.cpp" and compiles silently.
- Second one is the same code distributed in three files "MaClass.hpp", "MaClass.cpp" and "main.cpp". The issue come from this version.

```
$ g++ -o doit MaClass.cpp main.cpp
/usr/bin/ld : /tmp/cc9IOJE8.o : in function « main » :
main.cpp:(.text+0x10) : undefined reference to « test::example::MaClass::doit() »
collect2: error: ld returned exit status 1
```

But the error vanishes with namespace suppression or when changing the include from the header file to the implementation file.
Here are my questions :

- **What is the good way to include multifiles classes with namespaces ?**
- **How should one uses g++ in that case ?**

But I am a chatterbox ; here is the code :

**mainfull.cpp** : no pb when compiling with : g++ -o mainfull mainfull.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
namespace test {
        namespace example {
                class MaClass {
                public:
                        void doit();
                };
        }
}


int main() {
        test::example::MaClass c;
        c.doit();
        return 0;
}


namespace test {
        namespace example {
                void MaClass::doit() {
                        ::std::cout << "I did it !" << ::std::endl;
                }
        }
}
```

And here the version on witch I get doubts: (the whole remaining files)
**MaClass.hpp**

```
#ifndef MACLASS
#define MACLASS
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
        namespace example {
                class MaClass {
                public:
                        void doit();
                };
        }
}
#endif
```

**MaClass.cpp**

```
#include "MaClass.hpp"

namespace test {
        namespace example {
                void MaClass::doit() {
                        ::std::cout << "I did it !" << ::std::endl;
                }
        }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MaClass.hpp"

int main() {
        test::example::MaClass c;
        c.doit();
        return 0;
}
```

The issue occurs with :

```
g++ -o doit MaClass.cpp main.cpp -std=c++11
```

I don't know the reason of that. I know that the problem come from me and not from Fedora.
Any help would be apreciated. 
I have no problem on Visual Studio 2019 neither with the one nor the other version ; everything is automatic, I should have miss something.

Comment: You define `ns` when compiling `main.cpp`, but not when compiling `MaClass.cpp`. So `test::example::MaClass` is used but is not implemented. `::MaClass` is implemented but isn't used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,
I don't know why, the answer with or without your change is now :
<pre>
MaClass.cpp:8:22: error: definition of « void MaClass::doit() » is not in the namespace including « MaClass » [-fpermissive]
    8 |   void MaClass::doit() {
      |                      ^
main.cpp: In function « int main() »:
main.cpp:6:2: error: « test » haven't been declared
    6 |  test::example::MaClass c;
      |  ^~~~
main.cpp:10:2: error: « c » was not declared in this scope
   10 |  c.doit();
      |  ^
$
</pre>

Comment: What do you mean "my change"? I didn't make any changes.

Comment: I meant to explicitly define ns in MaClass.cpp.
I've only defined ns in order to switch easily from the version with a namespace to the version without it.
Sorry for that, I realise now that it is confusing.

Comment: Did you define it before `#include "MaClass.hpp"`, same as in `main.cpp`? Better still, define it on the command line, with `-Dns`. This way it's definitely going to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you ! I am learning new things with you. Unfortunatly, even like thatj the issue remain.
At first, the issue appeared in an other code without any "#define" in it. So, I've first built this simple code with "test" and "example" namespaces in a very simple maner without "#define ns". The issue was obvious to me.
Before asking to Stackoverflow, I've tried the version without namespace that compiled, an other with namespace that didn't compile. I wanted to post few code so that I've finally post a version with a "#define ns" to alows helpers to switch easily between two versions.

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that fails, and the exact and complete text of any error messages. I cannot follow your verbal descriptions.

Comment: I keep the two versions but second one is simplier and is only made with namespace. I won't confuse anymore with the "#define ns".
As is, the error response is exactly the one in the post.

Comment: The code as currently shown looks OK to me, and should build fine. Double-check all files - I suspect the code you actually build is in some way different from the code shown.

Comment: Ok I've just restarted my computer. This is ok now, without any changes. I don't understand why.  It is somewhat anoying to me because I haven't performed to compile the orignial code that is more bigger than this example. But nevermind this thread is closed now. For me, you have provided the good answer to that issue.
Thank you very much for your help.